# Capacitor GeoLocation No Results On Certain Android Devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, geolocation, capacitor

**Issue**

We are using the Capacitor Geolocation plugin with the getCurrentPosition() method to capture the users current location. It works fine on IOS but we're having issues with certain android devices.

On a few android phones when we fire the getCurrentPosition() method and the select "Only this time" when prompted for location permissions, it works the first time, but if you close the app and re open it, after firing getCurrentPosition() it never resolves and it doesn't fail with any error either. At least not within 10-15 seconds I haven't tried waiting any longer.

This is happening even if we pass in the options object with a timeout and max age

```
    let options = {timeout: 1000, maximumAge: 30000};
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options);
```

**Tech Stack**

- @ionic/angular: *^6.0.0*
- @angular/core: *~13.0.0*
- @capacitor/core: *3.4.1*
- @capacitor/geolocation: *^1.3.1*

**Android Studio Version**:
*Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3*
**Android Device**:

- Working
  *Samsung Galaxy A11 | Android version: 11 | Google Play system update: March 1 2022*
- Not working
  *Google Pixel 6 | Android version: 12 | Google Play system update: March 1 2022*
  *Galaxy S21+ 5g | Android version: 12 | Google Play System Update: March 1 2022*

**Code**

I've tried resolving the plugin function using try catch and promise callbacks as well, and same results with both methods.

```
     const coordinates = Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options)
        .then((res) => {
          var coordinates = {} as Coordinates;
          coordinates.latitude = res.coords.latitude;
          coordinates.longitude = res.coords.longitude;
          resolve(coordinates);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
```

```
    try{
      const coordinates = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options);
      resolve(coordinates.coords);
    }
    catch(err){
      reject("error");
    }
```

Comment: Did you check this link https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#approximate-request  since there're some changes applied on location permission on android 12.

Comment: @Mahmoud Thank you for providing this link. I've been reading through it. And you're right there does seem to be some changes that Android pushed with their permissions mechanism. For now we decided to just cache the geolocation for one day, till it prompts the user for permissions again. 

Once we find an actual solution to the problem ill update this post.

Comment: @Kevin, did you find a solution to this problem? Many guys are facing the same problem. If you could share the solution it would be great.

Comment: Please share any solution, this plugin seems broken still